# How to prevent a DataGrid from receiving any keyboard focus?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, focus, inputbinding

I have a Window, containing a Grid, which contains another Grid with InputBindings (on Enter and Delete keys) and, amongst other controls, a read-only DataGrid.

When the DataGrid has the focus, the InputBindings stop firing their commands. I'm then forced to manually give the focus to another control before the InputBindings can work.

How can I bypass this behavior? I tried playing with almost every input/keyboard related DataGrid's property with no success.

Here's the XAML, even though it doesn't bring much to the table:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding DoStuff}"/>
        <KeyBinding Key="Delete" Command="{Binding UndoStuff}"/>
    </Grid.InputBindings>
    <!-- stuff... -->
    <Grid >
        <!-- more stuff... -->
        <DataGrid IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding SomeProperty}" SelectedItem="{Binding SomeSelectedProperty, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <!-- blah -->
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: How about setting the `IsEnabled` property?

Comment: @Mike Nah, that would be too easy. :p The reason is that I still need to be able to select a row in the datagrid, because the UndoStuff command deletes it.

Answer (score 0):

you can handle the `PreviewGotKeyboardFocus` event.

```
<DataGrid Name="grid"  PreviewGotKeyboardFocus="grid_PreviewGotKeyboardFocus"

 private void grid_PreviewGotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Comment: This is always a emergency solution, but I really hoped there would be a pure XAML solution, hence the absence of c# tag in my question.